# How to open a settings page specific to devices using activity name or package name?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

I have a system settings activity called `.settings.AppLockSettingsActivity` and I want to launch that settings page when my app launches. App is a simple launcher doesn't show other pages except the settings.

Comment: "I want to launch that settings page when my app launches" -- give it the `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>` in your manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Add to this intent filters in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <activity
        android:name=".settings.AppLockSettingsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and if somewhere intent filters is written, delete them as well

Comment: it is throwing error `.settings.AppLockSettingsActivity` is not found in the project or the libraries.

Comment: can you try just .AppLockSettingsActivity

Comment: Tried, doesn't work.

Comment: What is the name of your activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file